# Eclipse keeps hanging/not responding

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Indigo v.3.7.2. For the past few weeks it has been really slow and keeps throwing not responding notification. Every time i click, scroll, type etc it freezes. I viewed the .log file but not sure what most of it means. I was told that there is an issue with the com.ibm.etools.webtools.json package and/or memory issues since cleanup is not getting done.

so my question is where do i find the above package? I tried opening the resource but it was not found. Also, how can I do a cleanup?

ty in advance..

Comment: Try to clean up the error log. Windows-"Show View"- under General "Error Log". Are you running on Windows? Try to reinstall.

Comment: yes im using Windows. I cleaned up error log and the problem still persists but not as frequently. Will try reinstalling next.

Comment: also in Eclipse config you can specify JVM params. increase heap memory -Xms1024m; -Xmx1024m; Try different version Java 64/32bit (sometimes helps)